# Can I transfer my saved KSP game files between platforms?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've been playing KSP on a XBOX, but I'd like to transfer all my save data over to a Windows 10 PC. Is this possible? If so, where are the files and what do I need to transfer?

Comment: On Windows, Linux and Mac the save files are located under _saves_ in the [KSP root directory](https://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Root_directory). I would assume the XBOX version does something similar, but I don't know for sure (and I couldn't immediately find the answer on Google, either).

Answer (score 1):

No, You can transfer your saved file to a PC, but Xbox One save files are encrypted. It won't run on PC until someone cracks the encryption and makes a decryption tool specifically for KSP from Xbox to PC.